# Cannot read properties of undefined error with GLTFLoader in Three.js

Tags: three.js, gltf

I am trying to adjust the properties of a GLB file outside of the loader (I want to be able to animate it later in another function)

Why is this code giving me the error: "Cannot read properties of undefined  (reading "scale")"
Something to do with scope I am imagining, but how do I fix this?

```
let sculpture

const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader()
    const modelFile = require(`./assets/Sculpture_lo5.glb`)
    loader.load(modelFile, (gltf) => {
      sculpture = gltf.scene
      sculpture.scale.set(0.35,0.35,0.35)
      scene.add(sculpture)
    })

sculpture.scale.z = 1
```

Comment: GLTFLoader is asynchronous. Sculpture is undefined while trying to set `scale.z`. I guess what you want to achieve is to set the z-scale to 1 in the callback after adding to scene?

Comment: Thanks, I want to potentially change the scale later in another function (in fact, I want to be able to animate it), so how would I then access this parameter outside of the loader?